# Content Hub Connector for Drupal

Tags: content-hub, sitecore-connect

I have been searching for a connector that will link up Content Hub to Drupal. I found a page in Marketplace, but the links seem to be missing from it so I'm assuming it may be outdated (https://www.sitecore.com/products/marketplace/tap/ch/acquia-drupal-connector). There was a video about it on YouTube, but it's in Japanese unfortunately.

My question is - is there a way to connect Sitecore Content Hub to Drupal the way that it connects to the Sitecore CMS?  Is Sitecore Connect the tool to use? If so, does that require a separate license? If not, is there just a generic connector? The info I'm finding online isn't very specific.

This link mentions Drupal, but doesn't indicate which connector to use:     https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/42/content-hub/integrate-with-sitecore--focus-on-integration.html

Answer (score 2):

I am uncertain whether the `Acquia Drupal Connector` is currently outdated. I suggest that you can check with `Sitecore Support/Sales` for confirming.

Other than that, there is indeed another approach to link Drupal with Sitecore Content Hub.

**Please kindly find this link [Drupal Connector](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/ja/developers/40/cloud-dev/drupal_connector.html) for your reference.**

**And the Drupal related plugins mentioned in the post can be obtained from [Iframedialog & Mconnector](https://mss-p-003-delivery.stylelabs.cloud/api/public/content/2CCTx0u21Kfj0MomnpR2bELeC?v=84bd19c8).**

This zip package extends `CKEditor` for use in creating content in Drupal by providing approved assets in an iFrame, thereby integrating with the `Sitecore Content Hub`. This extension is implemented through a `module and plugin` library.

Seems there is only Japanese edition of  this current post.

While you can read and follow it with some online translating tools or browswer extension, like [Immersive Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/immersive-translate/bpoadfkcbjbfhfodiogcnhhhpibjhbnh).
Also I listed the key steps for your reference.

**Installation steps:**

1. Download and unzip the zip package containing the two plugins `Iframedialog & Mconnector`, and copy the libraries and modules folders to the root directory of Drupal.
2. `Enable` the two plugins in Drupal backend.
3. In the `configuration` page, add a new toolbar group "Sitecore Plugin" containing Sitecore icon to the CKEditor editor.
4. Fill in the URL of Sitecore Content Hub in `MConnector` Settings.
5. Add Drupal's URL to `CORSConfiguration` in `PortalConfiguration` in Sitecore backend.

**Usage:**

1. In Drupal, click Add Content, choose `Basic` page, and click the icon in `Sitecore` plugin group to select assets from Sitecore.
2. Click the arrow icon of the asset to create or choose a public link, then click "Select" to import the asset into Drupal.

And `Sitecor Connect` is a new `SAAS DXP` product which neede a new `licensing`, I think.

If you would like to get more info of Sitecore Connect, please try to leave a messag at the bottom form in [Sitecore Connect Product](https://www.sitecore.com/products/connect) or chat with the `Sitecore consultant` online, and the expert would further help.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, thank you! I will check that out.

Comment: @VCBertini， It's a pleasure . If you have any new questions or need further help, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: Hi @VCBertini How is it going with that? Any new findings or progress?

Comment: we have unfortunately hit some snags in our project so this part of it has been put off for a while until we can get Content Hub in place to have something to connect to Drupal. I am excited to try it out still. Thank you for asking! I will post an update here once we have one.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Look forward to hearing back on your updated progress when you have more details to share. @VCBertini